# React trying to hide and show View dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

I'm trying to hide or show my component in the form. 
I have tried almost all the different ways found on the SO posts but none seems to work.

```
<BooleanInput source={"car"} label="cat.create.labelCar" onChange={this.onCarClick}/>
{
    this.state.shouldHide ?
        <ReferenceInput source={"parentCategory"} reference="categories"
                        label={'ad.filter.parentCategory'} allowEmpty>
                <SelectInput optionText={"name"}/>
        </ReferenceInput>
       : null
}
.
.
.
onCarClick = (event,value) => {
         this.setState({shouldHide: !value});
     };
```

I have checked that `onCarClick` function is calling also `render()`
gets called but UI is not updating.

I'm using [admin-on-rest](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest).

Comment: I will assume that within `onCarClick`, `value` is `undefined` hence `shouldHide` is always `true`. `this.state.shouldHide` is again `true` so you render `<ReferenceInput />`. Try `{shouldHide: !this.state.shouldHide}` instead of `{shouldHide: !value}`.

Comment: actually its not. i have checked it. its getting changed [true|false] on click

Comment: to clarify it for you, i have also placed log in `render(){         console.log(this.state.shouldHide);`

Comment: Can you post the code of the whole component?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/94d99fce4a469f525610d732988b80fc

Comment: If the console.log() inside render reports `this.state.shouldHide` as `false` it should not render `< ReferenceInput />`. Check if you have any change in the DOM elements. If you make a simpler component and try hiding a component you'll see for yourself that this is a proper way to hide a component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160973/discussion-between-arpl-and-user137124).

Comment: I'm having this same kind of problem.